# check whether fgets would block

Tags: c++, c, input, nonblocking, fgets

I was just wondering whether in C is it possible to peek in the input buffer or perform similar trickery to know whether a call to fgets would block at a later time.
Java allows to do something like that by calling BufferedReader.ready(), this way I can implement console input something like this:

```
while (on && in.ready()) { 
  line = in.readLine();
  /* do something with line */
  if (!in.ready())
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

this allows an external thread to gracefully shutdown the input loop by setting on to false; I'd like to perform a similar implementation in C without resorting to non portable tricks, I already know I can make a "timed out fgets" under unix by resorting to signals or (better, even though requering to take care of buffering) reimplement it on top of recv/select, but I'd prefer something that would work on windows too.

TIA

Comment: Select works on windows too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740141%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @nc3b: The Windows `select` function only works with sockets.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos: Oh, sorry didn't know :">

Answer (score 1):

Suggest to go with socket I/O routines,preferably poll() with required millisecond as timeout and eventually you can interpret timeout ( return value = -1 ) as unavailability of data in input buffer.
In my opinion,there is no non-blocking standard I/O function to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what are you talking about: a socket or a file handle?

For files there should be no blocking. The function returns immediately (besides of the I/O invocation itself).

For sockets - you may use the `ioctlsocket` function:
The following tells if there's a rcv data pending:

```
ULONG nSize;
ioctlsocket(sock, FIONREAD, &nSize);
```

The following transfers the socket into non-blocking mode:

```
ULONG nEnable = 1;
ioctlsocket(sock, FIONBIO, &nEnable);
```

When in Non-blocking mode - functions on socket never block. If they can't fulfill the request they return an error, and the error code is `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`

Plus, on Windows there're dozens of much more efficient methods. Those are:

- Using Overlapped I/O. This is non-trivial, but gives superior performance
- Associating socket with a waitable event. This transfers the socket to a non-blocking mode, plus the specified event is signaled when a network event occurs.
- Associate it with the window handle. This is convenient for UI-oriented programs.